# How to bring the same functionality in Azure SQL Databases that works on On-premises in Single Click

Tags: sql-server, database, azure, azure-sql-database

As there is a saying/proverb that '*Nothing is impossible*', Just Curious to know the way that we can get the same functionality in Azure SQL Databases that works on On-premises in Single Click?

**In On-Premises**,

At a single click of execution,
With the help of '***USE***' Command, we actually query the things in different databases.
*eg.,*

```
USE db_name1;
SELECT DB_NAME();
GO

USE db_name2;
SELECT DB_NAME();
GO
```

With the help of ***Query-->SQLCMD Mode***, we actually query the things in even different server and databases.
*eg.,*

```
:CONNECT server_name1
USE db_name1;
SELECT @@SERVERNAME;
GO

:CONNECT server_name2
USE db_name2;
SELECT @@SERVERNAME;
GO
```

*Note* - for example, i have mentioned some db and server name functions. In actual, will query tables to get required info.

Since, 'USE' Command wont works in Azure SQL Databases.
**How to achieve the same in Azure SQL Databases - At a single click of execution?**

Comment: You can't switch databases in a query in Azure; that is by design. If you want to use a Cross Database query, you have to set up External Data Sources, however, these can come with (significant) performance impacts.

Comment: Yup, i have tried external data sources as well. Also agree with the perf impacts it causes. So only curious to know the other ways. As this feature is not in cloud end, many would face hiccups right - developers, DBA etc.,.

Comment: If you require cross-database queries, then the "solution" is to not use Azure Databases and use either on premises SQL Server, or an Azure (or competitor) VM hosting SQL Server.

Comment: If you want to implement cross-database queries in Azure SQL data, you can use elastic query : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/elastic-query-overview

Comment: Thanks @Larnu and Jim Xu . Thanks for your valuable comments. Can u both post the same in answers, so that will mark it as answers.At Present, these are alone available options since no switching db support in azure sql db.

Comment: Neither of these are really answers, Arulmouzhi , they just give you the correct idea. If, for example, @JimXu puts an answer showing how to implemented a elastic queries on azure, while citing the documentation, that would be an answer.

Comment: Sure @Larnu! then, will wait whether anyone can give their opinions reg this or any other possible way. Hope one day azure sql db itself would support this functionality.

Comment: *"Hope one day azure sql db itself would support this functionality"* It won't, it's *by design*, as I said in my first comment.

Comment: Nothing is Permanent except change. may be it will need more design level change at present, so they wont take this currently.

Comment: I think you're missing the point of *why* you can't do what you're trying to do, @Arulmouzhi . Azure SQL Database and Hosted SQL Instances are *very* different "under the hood". Your 2 Azure SQL Databases are probably not even on the same host as each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Summarize the answer as below

Now Azure SOL database does not support `USE` statement. For more details, please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/transact-sql-tsql-differences-sql-server). besides, if you want Azure SQL Database team to add the function, you can upvote the [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217321-sql-database/suggestions/14822082-allow-the-use-statement-to-switch-between-database).

So if you want to do the cross-database query, you can use the [Azure SQL Database elastic query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/elastic-query-overview).

For example

1. create a certificate for the remote database

```
 CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = '<master_key_password>';
 CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL ElasticQueryCred
 WITH IDENTITY = '<username>',
 SECRET = '<password>';
```

2. Create an external data source fro the remote database

```
CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE MyElasticDBQueryDataSrc WITH
    (TYPE = RDBMS,
    LOCATION = '<server_name>.database.windows.net',
    DATABASE_NAME = '<>',
    CREDENTIAL = ElasticQueryCred,
) ;
```

3. Create an external table with the data source

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE [dbo].[CustomerInformation]
( 


)
WITH
( DATA_SOURCE = MyElasticDBQueryDataSrc)
```

4. Query the table

For more details, please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/elastic-query-getting-started-vertical) and the [blog](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-database-support-blog/cross-database-query-in-azure-sql-database/ba-p/369126)

Besides, as @Larnu said, you also can host your SQL server on Azure VM to implement your need.